# Azure Devops YAML pipeline to accept Dictionary key value pair

Tags: azure-devops, tags, terraform-provider-azure, azure-pipelines-yaml

Azure Devops Yaml pipeline to deploy terraform Azure VM having `main.tf` and `var.tf` so now for Tags will send json like this format
`"Tags": {"Application": "Marklogic", "CostCenter": "CoE", "Environment": "Test", "Support": "xyz.com", "AvailabilityTime": "24*7", "Owner": "xyza@.com", "BU": "CIS"}` -below is my yaml pipeline

```yaml
trigger: none
#########################
# Declare Build Agents:-
#########################
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
######################
#DECLARE PARAMETERS:-
######################
parameters:
- name: ResourceGroup
  displayName: Please Provide the Resource Group Name:-
  type: string
  default: <Please provide the required RG Name>

- name: Location
  displayName: Please Provide the Location:-
  type: string
  default: <Please provide the required location>
- name: Virtual_Network
  displayName: Please Provide the Virtual_Network Name:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name>

- name: Subnet
  displayName: Please Provide the subnet name:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name>

- name: Public_ip
  displayName: Please Provide the IP Name:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name>

- name: Dns
  displayName: Please Provide the Dns name:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name>
  
- name: Network_Security_Group
  displayName: Please Provide the NSG Name:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name>

- name: Network_Interface
  displayName: Please Provide the NIC name:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name>

- name: Virtual_Machine_Name
  displayName: Please Provide the VM Name:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name>

- name: Size
  displayName: Please Provide the Size of vm:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name>

- name: Username
  displayName: Please Provide the UserName:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name>

- name: Password
  displayName: Please Provide the password:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name>


 
- name: Tags
  displayName: Tags
  type: object
  default: |
    {
        "Application": "C360",
        "CostCenter": "test",
        "Environment": "QA",
        "Support": "CIS-Cloud_support",
        "AvailabilityTime": "test",
        "Owner": "xyth@.com",
        "BU": "CIS"
    }
 
######################
#DECLARE VARIABLES:-
######################
variables:


  TF_VAR_RESOURCEGROUP: ${{ parameters.ResourceGroup }}
  TF_VAR_LOCATION: ${{ parameters.Location }} 
  TF_VAR_VIRTUAL_NETWORK: ${{ parameters.Virtual_Network }}
  TF_VAR_SUBNET: ${{ parameters.Subnet }}
  TF_VAR_PUBLIC_IP: ${{ parameters.Public_ip }}
  TF_VAR_DNS: ${{ parameters.Dns }}
  TF_VAR_NETWOK_SECURITY_GROUP: ${{ parameters.Network_Security_Group }}
  TF_VAR_NETWORK_INTERFACE: ${{ parameters.Network_Interface }}  
  TF_VAR_VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME: ${{ parameters.Virtual_Machine_Name }}
  TF_VAR_SIZE: ${{ parameters.Size }}
  TF_VAR_USERNAME: ${{ parameters.Username }}
  TF_VAR_PASSWORD: ${{ parameters.Password }}
  TF_VAR_TAGS: ${{ parameters.Tags }}
  
###################
# Declare Stages:-
###################
stages:
  - stage: tfvalidate
    jobs:
      - job: validate
        variables: 
         - group: AzureDevopsCred
        
        continueOnError: false
        steps:
          - task: TerraformInstaller@0
            inputs:
              terraformVersion: 'latest'

          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: init
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'init'
              workingDirectory: 'LaunchStack/terraform/azure/testmarklogic'
              backendServiceArm: 'SaaS_Automationaccount_OIDC_TEST'
              backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroup)
              backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: $(StorageAccount)
              backendAzureRmContainerName: $(Container)
              backendAzureRmKey: $(TfstateFile)
          
          
  - stage: tfdeploy
    condition: succeeded('tfvalidate')
    dependsOn: tfvalidate
    jobs:
      - job: apply
        variables: 
           - group: AzureDevopsCred
          #- template: variable.dev.yaml
        steps: 
          - task: TerraformInstaller@0
            inputs:
              terraformVersion: 'latest'
           
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3  
            displayName: init
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'init'
              workingDirectory: 'LaunchStack/terraform/azure/testmarklogic'
              #backendServiceArm: ${{ variables.serviceconnection  }}
              backendServiceArm: 'SaaS_Automationaccount_OIDC_TEST' 
              backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroup)
              backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: $(StorageAccount)
              backendAzureRmContainerName: $(Container)
              backendAzureRmKey: $(TfstateFile)
           

          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: validate
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'validate'
              workingDirectory: 'LaunchStack/terraform/azure/testmarklogic'
          
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: plan
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'plan'
              workingDirectory: 'LaunchStack/terraform/azure/testmarklogic'
              
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: apply
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'apply'
              workingDirectory: 'LaunchStack/terraform/azure/testmarklogic'
              commandOptions: '-auto-approve'
              environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'SaaS_Automationaccount_OIDC_TEST'
```

**var.tf**

```terraform
variable "RESOURCEGROUP" {
  type    = string
}
variable "LOCATION" {
  type    = string
  
}
variable "VIRTUAL_NETWORK" {
  type    = string
}
variable "SUBNET" {
  type    = string
}
variable "PUBLIC_IP" {
  type    = string
}
variable "DNS" {
  type    = string
}
variable "TAGS" {
  type = map(string) 
}
```

**main.tf**

```terraform
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "machine" {
  name                = var.VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.windows.location
  size                = var.SIZE
  admin_username      = var.USERNAME
  admin_password      = var.PASSWORD
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.windows.id,
  ]
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_network_interface.windows
   
 ]
  plan {
           publisher = "marklogic"
            product = "marklogic-developer-9"
            name = "ml9011-centos"
         }

  os_disk {
    name              = "myOsDisk"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  tags = var.TAGS

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "marklogic"
    offer     = "marklogic-developer-9"
    sku       = "ml9011-centos"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  computer_name  = "redhatVM"
    #admin_username = "azureuser"
    disable_password_authentication = false
    

}
```

Incase when im trying it from postman it is taking default Tags are replaced it is not taking which passing the values for Tags default is not mandatory that should work with any kind of values which im passing as dynamically may be i missed some syntax's, Please help to solve this. Thanks In advance